# Pass instance method as function pointer to C Library

Tags: objective-c, c, function-pointers

I am writing an Objective-C application that uses a C Library. The issue which i am currently facing is that the C Library has a structure where some field are function pointers later used as callbacks. How can i convert an Objective-C instance method to a function pointer and pass it to the library?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You will need to provide the C callback function within the Objective-C class implementation file, and this will only work if the callback is able to use a *context* pointer of some sort.

So imagine the C callback signature is like this:

```
void myCallback(void *context, int someOtherInfo);
```

Then within the Objective-C class implementation file you need to use that callback to trampoline back into your Objective-C class (using the *context* pointer as the instance of the class to invoke):

```
// Forward declaration of C callback function
static void theCallbackFunction(void *context, int someOtherInfo);

// Private Methods
@interface MyClass ()
- (void)_callbackWithInfo:(int)someOtherInfo;
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)methodToSetupCallback
{
    // Call function to set the callback function, passing it a "context"
    setCallbackFunction(theCallbackFunction, self);
    ...
}

- (void)_callbackWithInfo:(int)someOtherInfo
{
    NSLog(@"Some info: %d", someOtherInfo);
}

@end

static void theCallbackFunction(void *context, int someOtherInfo)
{
    MyClass *object = (MyClass *)context;
    [object _callbackWithInfo:someOtherInfo];
}
```

If your C callback function does not accept some sort of *context* info, then:

1. It's broken and this should be fixed/reported as a bug.
2. You will need to rely on storing a *pointer-to-self* at global, static, scope to be used by the C callback function.  This will limit the number of instances of `MyClass` to one!

Comment: I'd like to cast my vote that the phrase "trampoline back" somehow become the official term for this. It's awesome.

Comment: +1 - What if library doesn't provide params of `void* context`?

Comment: @MySpecialPurpose The term trampoline is an old one I'm afraid, and not my invention.  I encountered it first when integrating C++ classes with thread creation functions, where such a trampoline method was required.

Comment: yeah, awesome answer. :) thanks. *I wish* I could upvote one more time for your quick-ness :p

Comment: @AdilSoomro Many thanks.  Just being appreciated is enough for me.

Comment: Just to add something about callbacks. some times libraries take `self` as `my_lib_core_set_user_info(self, myLibInstance);` type thing. Then in callback that core instance is passed, you can extract `self` from there something like `MyClass *instance = (MyClass *)my_lib_core_get_user_info(lib_instance);`

Comment: @AdilSoomro Agreed; the *context* will still be passed back in the callback itself, or will be provided via some other means.  It's not clear how this works with the C library the OP is using, so it's not possible to provide a more accurate answer than this.

Comment: There was no context and only a function pointer could be passed what limited the callback to only a static function and as you mentioned in the end it limited the number of instances of my class to one. But as with most nix libraries it was GPL-ed so implementing a context was not much of a hassle.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks. With ARC, I had to replace 
"MyClass *object = (MyClass *)context;" with
"MyClass *object = (MyClass *)CFBridgingRelease(context);"

Comment: @BeccaP I'm not sure there is a need to transfer ownership given (I assume) that the context pointer "object" is being retained elsewhere.  Did you try with `(__bridge MyClass *)`?

Comment: Yes, that ended up being important, @trojanfoe. Thank you.

Comment: Appreciate, great answer!